# Camel-netty4: how to wait response before send next request

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I have created route that accept request from multiple producers and send to a remote server by using netty4 with request-response. However, when camel is sending a request to remote server and waiting for response, next incoming request is received and want to send to remote server but got IOException as camel cannot receive response.

**So, how to set Camel-Netty4 send request and wait for response before send next.**

The route configuration:
from("direct:DirectProcessOut?block=true")
.to("netty4:tcp://192.168.1.2:8000?sync=true&synchronous=true&reuseChannel=true")

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into a similar issue trying to send out several messages at a time based on rows in a database table. The calls wouldn't wait for each other to complete and essentially stepped on each other and either hung or blew up.

The solution I eventually found was to use a message queue. Take in your requests and route them into a single activemq route.

So something like:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
       <from uri="direct:direct:DirectProcessOut"/>
       <to uri="activemq://processOutQueue"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
       <from uri="activemq://processOutQueue"/>
       <to uri="netty4:tcp://192.168.1.2:8000?sync=true&amp;synchronous=true&amp;reuseChannel=true"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

My case was a little different, so I'm not sure if this will preserve your message you want to send. But hopefully it gives you a place to start.